Stop casting shadow only on specific object
I have a flying object and I don't want it to cast shadows only on 3 meshes, but everything else stays the same, so only isolate it for 3 specific meshes. If that's not possible eliminate shadow casting, but keep his shadows at least.

Answering with a link is not the best you can do... Read why is linking bad? I will answer the question in an hour.

This is not related to shadow catchers, as they do the inverse of what you want: Be invisible except for the shadows cast on them. As for how to effect what you want, I might suggest using multiple render layers, one of which contains the three buildings but not the flying object. By the way, is this in Cycles or EEVEE?

maybe try with the Compositor?

@TheLabCat ... it can be related to ShadowCatcher if you choose a workflow to dupli "three objects", set as SC and for and enable it for second View Layer (aka Render Layer), right :) ... BTW ahkai - your scenario is not to much clear, there could play a role many things (render engine, indirect lights, glass etc.  so would be helpful to share more info about your project to offer you helpful solution. Thanks

@vklidu At first I thought of shadowcatchers, but in this case we don't necessarily need objects to remain transparent, maybe that would improve render times?

I tried light/shadow linking, but it can't partially disable the shadow.
The only way I see to do this is to separate objects into different View Layers, you place object that casts a shadow in one view layer with objects you need it to cast shadow on, the other view layer should contain objects you don't want to affect with this shadow, plus lights and objects whose shadows you want to keep.
